# Custom assignment operator doesn't work with pipes

Tags: r, magrittr

I'm trying to create a custom assignment operator, the basic functionality is as below.

```
`%<-%` <- function(x, value) {
    x <- rlang::enquo(x)
    name <- rlang::quo_name(x) 
    assign(name, value, envir = .GlobalEnv)    
}
```

With just 2 arguments, it works as intended, however, when used with a pipe sequence it saves the first, not the final value. It works if I put the pipe sequence in brackets, though.

```
tmp %<-% 1              # OK, tmp = 1
rm(tmp)
tmp %<-% 1 %>% sum(2)   # not OK, tmp = 1, it should be 3
rm(tmp)
tmp %<-% (1 %>% sum(2)) # OK tmp = 3
```

Is there a way to make it work without using brackets?

Comment: It returns 3 but it doesn't save your output right?

Comment: It saves 1 into tmp and returns 3. I'll edit the example to show this.

Comment: @mnist It does in the sense that apparently it cannot be done. :) OK then. Thanks!